# Flask/Python Login

Tags: python, flask, ldap

I have Python/Flask application with a login screen. My goal is to utilize LDAP authentication in unison with my Python/Flask app.

The issue that I am running into is this:

> raise RuntimeError('The session is unavailable because no secret '
>   RuntimeError: The session is unavailable because no secret key was
>   set. Set the secret_key on the application to something unique and
>   secret.

I have a secret key, and I still get the same error when I comment it out.

Here is my code:

```
import token
from flask import Flask, session
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager

app = Flask(name)
#app.secret_key = 'welfhwdlhwdlfhwelfhwlehfwlehfelwehflwefwlehflwefhlwefhlewjfhwelfjhweflhweflhwel'
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
app.config['LDAP_AUTH_SERVER'] = 'LDAPLocation.com'
app.config['LDAP_PORT'] = '636'
app.config['LDAP_TOP_DN'] = 'CN=something here,OU=somethingHere,OU=SomeService Accounts,dc=magic,dc=pumpum,DC=com Xe'
app.config['LDAP_BIND_USER_PASSWORD'] = 'pssword'
app.register_blueprint(token, url_prefix='/auth')

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'

from app.auth.views import auth

app.register_blueprint(auth)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the secret key.

You can set the key by :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = 'mysecret'
```

Or, if you plan to use `gunicorn` in future to deploy your app, place the `app.secret_key` after defining app.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add :

```
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'my super secret key'
```

or

```
app.secret_key = 'my super secret key'
```

[Flask session](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#sessions)

Comment: I still get the same error with or with out the secret key